# golang big numbers to readable/ string formats

Tags: json, go

I have a json response from an API that look like this after I use json. Unmarshal then save it to an interface variable.

```
 map[message_num:3 
 task_num:0 
 name: test_room 
 type:my role:member sticky:true unread_num:0 
 room_id:3.190762e+06 ]
```

I want to get the room_id, but its not readable

```
 3.190762e+06
```

I want to format this to a string, so I can use it to send a post request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract `room_id` from your JSON as a string `"3.190762e+06"`.
Then you can:

- convert it to a (readable) float, with [`strconv.ParseFloat()`](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseFloat),
- and convert it back to a string, with [`fmt.Sprintf()`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf).

See [this example](http://play.golang.org/p/L6uMIHKrj8):

```
i, err := strconv.ParseFloat("3.190762e+06", 64)
if err == nil {
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%.0f\n", i)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Output:

```
3190762
```